# React, setstate does not activate inside useEffect function for one variable, works for another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I am trying to display a map with the users current location combined with some additional geometry. I can access these data and display them, but when it is time to show another page I want to unsubscribe from the location updates. To do this I need an id (according to the documentation of the `navigator.geolocation`). I am trying to store this id in a state variable, but for some reason I cannot set this id inside my `useEffect` function.

The puzzling thing is that I also store the geometry data in a state variable, and I can set that just fine from inside the `useEffect` loop. I just cannot figure out what is the difference between the `features` and the `watcherId` state variables. When I run this code the `waId` gets set, but the watcher id always remains `-1`, and therefore I cannot use it to unsubscribe from the location changed event.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import {Point} from 'ol/geom';
import {transform, fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import MapWrapper from './Base_MapWrapper';

function Card_Map(props) {
    const [ features, setFeatures ] = useState([]);
    const [ watcherId, setWatcherId ] = useState(-1);

    useEffect( () => {
        const wktOptions = {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        }
        const parsedFeatures = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(props.jsonData, wktOptions);

        let waId = -1;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log('location available');
            waId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                let coorArr = [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude];
                let newCoors = transform(coorArr, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
                let fPoint = new Feature({
                    geometry: new Point(newCoors)
                });
                let theFeatures = [fPoint, ...parsedFeatures];
                setFeatures(theFeatures);
            });
            console.log(waId);
            setWatcherId(waId);
        }
        else {
            setFeatures(parsedFeatures);
        }
        console.log(watcherId);

        //this is the destructor 
        return () => {
            if (watcherId != -1)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcherId);
            }
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            <MapWrapper features={features} cssClass={props.cssClass} />
        </div>
    ) 
}

export default Card_Map
```

Comment: How do you know watcherId doesn't get set? If you are relying on console.log(watcherID) for this, then that always returns -1. State setters updates the state async. So your console.log executes before updating to a new state. Looking over your useEffect dependency array, it will only get unloaded when the component unmounts.

Comment: You're setting a callback which uses a set state function in `useEffect` which is not going to work.  When this component inevitably rerenders whatever original component `setFeatures` was referencing is gone and will not update the state of the current, rerendered component.

Comment: @RaduDiță That is a good point, however when I move the console.log inside the destructor it still shows a -1, also I get this error: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application", which I assume means the subscription was not cancelled.

Comment: @possum can you explain how it should be done instead? I thought the idea of the useEffect was that is allows us to run a function once only (or if a watched variable changes), since I provided an empty watch array it should only be executed once. So if I do not have access to setWatcherId inside that function, why do I have access to setFeatures? If I remove that line (setFeatures(theFeatures)) I no longer see anything rendered in my map, so that state must be set correctly, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: @possum That's wrong. State setters are guaranteed to not change between re-renders. That's why you never add them as dependencies to useEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that you are trying to use `watcherId` which will keep a reference of the value before calling `setWatcherId`.

I'm pretty sure that you have a warning saying that you should use `watcherId` as a dependency, but this will trigger another re-render and a new set and so on.

You don't actually need a state here, you can just use `waId` so you should end up with the following:

```
function Card_Map(props) {
    const [ features, setFeatures ] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        const wktOptions = {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        }
        const parsedFeatures = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(props.jsonData, wktOptions);

        let waId = -1;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log('location available');
            waId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                let coorArr = [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude];
                let newCoors = transform(coorArr, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
                let fPoint = new Feature({
                    geometry: new Point(newCoors)
                });
                let theFeatures = [fPoint, ...parsedFeatures];
                setFeatures(theFeatures);
            });
        }
        else {
            setFeatures(parsedFeatures);
        }

        //this is the destructor 
        return () => {
            if (waId != -1)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(waId);
            }
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            <MapWrapper features={features} cssClass={props.cssClass} />
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

If you do need the `id` in another place, keep the state, but still use `waId` in the cleanup function.

Comment: That totally fixed it, thanks a million. So if I understand correctly, the useEffect has sort of its own scope, the variables (like watcherId) are put into the function and remain unchanged until the function is called. You do not have access to the current state from inside these functions, with the exception of state setters which don't change, which is why they can be used to give values back, is that correct? 
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: yes, you got it. useEffect generates a closure and has a ref to the current variables, which are "old values".